# Return length of label, in pixels

Tags: logo-lang

How do I return the length, in pixels, of a string that will be printed on the screen by the `etiquette` command?

The command `longueuretiquette` does not work properly because it does not return in pixels.

I'm working on the Logo language

Comment: Logo programming language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the problem.

The reason for the `longueuretiquette` command does not work was a bug of IDE (xLogo) with the `axis`

Comment: Please clarify your answer.  There "was a bug" doesn't help future readers of this post.  Thanks.

Comment: There is a bug in the IDE that was using, in this case, xLogo. If using the grill, as through the "axis" command does not return the correct value of the size of a word with "longueuretiquette" command.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? Is there a workaround?  Is there an issue tracker URL you can point at?

Comment: I just deactivated the grid. It is not a "solution", but solved the problem.